# How to crawl urls having space using Apache Nutch?

Tags: nutch

I am using nutch for crawling but it is getting failed on urls which have space.  I have gone through this link http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/URL-with-Space-td619127.html but did not get satisfactory answer.

It works for URL in the seed.txt file but wont work for URLs in the parsed content of a page

I used a URL that has spaces in the conf/seed.txt file and it replaces the space with %20 and I was able to crawl the page.
I have added following in regex-normalize.xml

```
<regex> 
 <pattern> </pattern> 
 <substitution>%20</substitution> 
</regex>
```

Also, I added the reference of regex-normalize.xml in nutch-site.xml. But still I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi abhijeet, have you tried looking at what the URLs in the parsed content of the pages look like? Do they have the spaces intact, or are spaces replaced with '%20' ?

Comment: Hi Yanhan, thanks for your response..urls are of following pattern:      http://www.abc.com/efg ghi

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with more characters so I changed Fetcher.java!
New URLs add to Queue in "feeding" section!
you have to find this line:

```
nURL.set(url.toString());
```

and replace it with this:

```
nURL.set(URIUtil.encodeQuery(url.toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and added this to my regex-normalize.xml

```
<regex> 
   <pattern>&#x20;</pattern> 
   <substitution>%20</substitution> 
</regex>
```